# How to do logical and operation on list of bool objects list?

Tags: python, list, logical-operators

I have a list of `bool` objects list like this:

```
[[True, True, True, False], [False, True, True, False], [False, False, True, True]]
```

I want to bit and those lists and get the result:

```
[False, False, True, False]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: That is not a list of bits. That is a list of `bool` objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, I've edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you use boolean, you could [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and then use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
data = [[True, True, True, False], [False, True, True, False], [False, False, True, True]]
result = [all(e) for e in zip(*data)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[False, False, True, False]
```

Comment: This does logical `and`, not bitwise `&`

Comment: Since bools are just one bit wouldn't it be the same?

Comment: I know, the result is the same for this particular case. But since the question asks specifically ... ;-)

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks, you are all the correct answer what I wanted. I've changed my question title and content to `bool objects`, so I choose this answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and the bitwise "and" [`operator.and_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.and_), as well as the typical [`zip(*...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) transposition pattern:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

lst = [[True, True, True, False], [False, True, True, False], [False, False, True, True]]

[reduce(and_, x) for x in zip(*lst)]
# [False, False, True, False]
```

Comment: It would, but it is semantically incorrect as there is no in-place update (don't confuse `reduce` with in-place). Note that `&` and `&=` are two entirely different operators. Every type can overload them as they please. That, for many types, `a = a & b` and `a &= b` are equivalent, is purely conventional.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically use the bitwise `&` operator, then you can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> l = [[True, True, True, False], [False, True, True, False], [False, False, True, True]]
>>> [reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, lst) for lst in zip(*l)]
[False, False, True, False]
```

We can also create our own mini function to replace `lambda`:

```
>>> def bitwise_and(x, y):
...     return x & y
...
>>> [reduce(bitwise_and, lst) for lst in zip(*l)]
[False, False, True, False]
```

Or just use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module, as shown in [@schwobaseggl's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360567/how-to-use-bit-and-operation-on-list-of-bit-lists/61360652#61360652) answer.